# Informatica power center , incremental load

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement ,that I have 5 rows which contains primary key as ID,i need to do insert whenever I got change in primary/got new records,and i need to update only when I got new values in existing records..

I tried an approach by using IIF(ISNULL(ID),I,U)
it is inserting the new records,but the problem is like it is updating all the existing records even without any change in values..but I want to update only when the change in columns happens..

Could you guys please give ur solutions to update rows only when I got change in columns..otherwise the rows should not go to insert/update..

So,i need to insert when new row/primary key changes and i need to update only when change in columns happens. If both the above conditions are not met the records should not go to either of the targets.

Thank you

Comment: you need to do a merge strategy

Comment: How to do that ,could you pls explain.

Comment: Either you have to compare every column between the source and target rows (which is really only practicable for a small number of columns) or you create a hash for all relevant columns for each source and target row and compare the hashes. If the hashes are different then you update the row, otherwise you ignore it

Comment: Normally source db has something like update date/last refresh date/ or process id etc to indicate these are rows that were changed. You can use them to identify... If you dont have one, you can check change log like mv log in oracle for changed rows. Else last resort is some trigger to capture changes.